# String with spaces in quoted python argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am running into an odd issue with passing an argument with spaces in a Python3 argument.

For example:

```
camera.timelapse.upload --file="dcim/20200821.mp4" --title="20200821" --description="Timelapse for 20200821" --noauth_local_webserver
```

results in:

> camera.timelapse.upload.py: error: unrecognized arguments: for 20200821

---

Another example:

```
camera.timelapse.upload --file="dcim/20200821.mp4" --title="20200821 test" --description="Timelapse for 20200821" --noauth_local_webserver
```

results in:

> camera.timelapse.upload.py: error: unrecognized arguments: test for 20200821.

In this case you can see it is seeing each spaced out word as a separate argument, even though they are quoted.

I have tried with and without the =, and the result is the same.   I have tried with single quotes instead of double quotes and again, the result is the same.

Comment: We need to see the code that is handling the argument parsing to be able to help with this issue. Quoting the strings with spaces should work.

Comment: It is argparser that handles it.   `from oauth2client.tools import run_flow, argparser`

Comment: It would still be useful to see the code which raised the error, and the value of the string at the time it was raised

Comment: `argparser.add_argument("--title", default="Timelapse", help="Set the video title")`

Comment: Have you tested to see what your terminal is passing your program? Print(sys.args). It could be your choice of terminal and not python. For example, you might need to put escape characters, like "dcim\/20200821.mp4" or "time\ thing". What does tour terminal do with quotes?

Comment: That looks right for the argparse. Do you know that the method or object receiving the string is getting the right value?

Comment: @BobbyOcean module 'sys' has no attribute 'args'

Comment: it'll be [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Comment: Right argv, not arg. I am on mobile, forgive me.

Comment: @puffin ['/home/pi/camera.timelapse/camera.timelapse.upload.py', '--file=dcim/20200821.mp4', '--title=2020821', 'test', '--description=Timelapse', 'for', '20200821', '--noauth_local_webserver']

Comment: Huh wacky. You can try using single quotes, and potentially escaping the spaces: `--title=20200821\ test`.

Comment: also try running the script manually. If its a module `python -m <module> <args>` or if script just `python <script>`

Comment: Ahhh, that fixed it.   It does not like the bash_alias I guess?

`function camera.timelapse.upload { sudo python3 ~/camera.timelapse/camera.timelapse.upload.py $@; }`

Comment: if you want the alias you can use `alias camera.timelapse.upload="sudo python3 ~/camera.timelapse/camera.timelapse.upload.py"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @puffin, the issue was with the alias -- not the argument.  The alias has to have it's argument variable quoted.   For example.

```
function camera.timelapse { sudo python3 ~/camera.timelapse/camera.timelapse.py "$@"; }
```